# How to discover the crypt method?

Tags: encryption, database-connection, connection-string

I got a little system here that encrypt a connection string used in SQL Server.

When I put a connection like:

> Server=WK-001;Database=4RSYSTEM;User Id=user1;Password=user123;

I receive that encrypted string:

> rJUDUypxZUSmrFHgkTW0GY3Xpf97WOaWIa4dbwJK85an9QsCWMJbjaKT8LxAUEjl9hPo0gW3CVA7IiTpOvqAcw==

Btw, now I got a encrypted string (generate by the same "system") and I need to decrypt. There's a way to discover the encryption method / how decrypt it?

Comment: I would say that this is Base64, there are a lot of online tools for that if you want to try.

Comment: *"I got a little system here that encrypt a connection string used in SQL Server."* Look into that little system and reverse the method (if it is reversable).